# QChar stores a negative Latin1 code for multiply sign '×'

Tags: qt, qchar

I want to get the Latin1 code for multiply sign `×`, but when I check the value inside the `QChar` it has `-41'×'`.

My code:

```
QString data = "×";
QChar m = data.at(0);
unsigned short ascii = (unsigned short)m.toLatin1();
```

When I debug, in the second line I see the `QChar` value is `-41'×'`.

I changed the code:

```
unsigned int ascii = c.unicode();
```

But I get the value 215 rather and I expect 158.

Comment: You're converting the character to Latin-1 encoding. I think ASCII table doesn't have this character. And ASCII codes are 8-bit, while it seems you intend to get 16 bits. You probably should use `m.unicode()` to get the character code in Unicode table. It returns unsigned short, so there is no need to cast it.

Answer (score 4):

The multiply sign `×` is not an ascii sign, as you can see when checking `man ascii` if you are on a unix system.

What its value is depends on the encoding, see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) for its UTF representations.
For example on UTF-8 it has the value `0xC397` which are two bytes.
As is mentioned on the unicode page I linked 215 is the decimal value to represent this character in UTF-16 encoding, which is what `c.unicode()` returns.
I don't know why you expect 158.

There is an ascii multiply sign though, which is `*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Latin1 code table](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/iso8859-1.html), it's obvious that `×` *is indeed* encoded as 215, or -41. Qt is giving you the correct result.

Your mistakes are:

1. Assuming that Latin1 is equivalent to ASCII. Latin1 merely contains ASCII, but is the superset: it defines 2x more codes than ASCII does.
2. Assuming that `×` is represented in the ASCII. It is not.

I have no clue where you got the idea that Latin1-encoded `×` should be 158. Surely it didn't come from the Latin1 code table! Incidentally, the Latin1 and UTF-8 encodings of `×` are identical.

Comment: I asked because I am newer working with ascii code and I had doubts.  I did some research, and I read that `×` is an extended ASCII code, so I did assumed it belongs to ASCII. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Robert ASCII is ASCII. There's no such thing as "extended" ASCII. It is something else but not ASCII anymore.